# HTTP_REFERER from link in FRAMESET sends different values on different computers?

Tags: html, http-headers, frames

I have a `<frameset>` which contains two `<frame>` tags: a navigation frame (A) and a content frame (B)

```
-------------------------
|     |                 |
|     |                 |
|     |                 |
|  A  |        B        |
|     |                 |
|     |                 |
|     |                 |
-------------------------
```

```
  <FRAMESET rows="*" cols="130,*" border=0>
    <FRAME scrolling="no" name="navFrame" FrameBorder=0 src="navFrame.aspx">
    <FRAME src="" name="mainFrame"></FRAME>
  </FRAMESET>
```

The page is called `main.aspx`, while side A is called `navFrame.aspx`. When I click on a link in the navigation frame, it loads the content in frame B.

One of the content pages for B uses `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")`, however this value is `navFrame.aspx` on some computers, and `main.aspx` on other computers.

Both computers used an embedded web browser that is part of another software product (javascript tells me its  IE7), so I don't think it's an issue with browser versions.

And I'm not sure if it matters or not, but the content page is an https page located on another domain, and it uses the external URL to access it.

What determines what the `HTTP_REFERER` is in framed windows?

Comment: WOW!  I don't remember the last time I saw a `<FRAMESET>` tag!

Comment: @Rocket Not my code... I'm just debugging it >.<

Comment: @Rocket I would guess about 51 seconds ago! ;-)

Comment: I assume https is not part of the equation? What kinds of URLs is the application accessing, local or Internet ones? What browser engine is the app using?

Comment: You could try appending the correct referer to the URL (or save it in a session) to be sure its the same each time.

Comment: @Pekka The content page is an https page located on another domain, and it uses the external URL for it. Would that matter? And javascript tells me the embedded browser engine is IE7.

Comment: IIRC, switching to https (or even, going from page to page with https?) causes the referer to be removed in IE, if not even in all browsers. My memory is hazy but there definitely was something to that effect. Maybe you'll have to pass the referer in a GET parameter or through JS (although the latter isn't an option if you're crossing domains)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: *HTTP_REFERER* is not reliable.

The value depends on the *referer* header sent by the the client (webbrowser) to the server. As it can be both manipulated as well as mingled by technical issues, it can not be trusted. For example, securing forms using the *referer* won't work because spammers can manipulate the GET and POST values, faking any referer they like.

My best tip is: some browsers offer the option to disable sending the *HTTP_REFERER*, you might want to take another look at the configuration of your web browsing client (and/or the browsing client your application *embeds*).